# Name of file during compile time in Progress 4gl

Tags: preprocessor, progress-4gl, openedge

I want to make a compile time test of a file. The set-up is as follow.

```
1. We have procedure files proc1.p, proc2.p, ... proc1000.p.
2. All procedure files proc1.p, proc2.p, ... proc1000.p have a common include file incl.i
```

I would like to have pre-process variable in incl.i that carries the name of the parent procedure in order to invoke different behaviour during compile time.

What I tried

/* incl.i */
   &SCOPED-DEFINE procName {&FILE-NAME}

this does not work {&FILE-NAME} evaluates to the name of the include file.

Now, THIS-PROCEDURE:FILE-NAME holds the name of the procedure file, but it is not known at compile time.

Any ideas? I do not want to add a new input parameter to the include - thus updating proc1.p...proc1000.p.

Answer (score 3):

Pre-processors are the road to hell... but if you insist you could create an &GLOBAL-DEFINE in the parent procedure.  Something like this:

```
/* parent.p
 */

&GLOBAL-DEFINE parentName {&FILE-NAME}

{include.i}


/* include.i
 */

display "{&parentName}".
```

Comment: Thanks Tom, you have the picture. This would work but it is not better than sending the FILE-NAME value as a parameter - which is what I want to avoid. In particular, as I mentioned in the end, I don't want to update all files containing the include. +1 for the effort!

Comment: By the way in OpenEdge Architect (and Dev studio) there is a view called "& Preprocess" which one can use to "read" the pre-processes - very useful. Otherwise I agree, pre-processes should be used with care.

Comment: Yes, you'd have to touch the parents -- but at least it would just be the one line rather than every place where a parameter might be needed.